# How to install SSL Certificate on Windows Server 2012 R2 without IIS

Tags: ssl-certificate, windows-server-2012-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 server running SQL Server 2012 with Reporting Services.

I want to be able to use the Reporting Services Report Manager over HTTPS instead of the default HTTP.

How can I install an SSL Certificate and apply it to SSRS? I do not have, nor want to install, ISS on this box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use the Certificates snap-in in Microsoft Management Console (MMC.exe) to install your certificate, actually.  And since an SSL certificate is a machine certificate, you want to be sure to open the Certificates snap-in for the local computer, not for your user.

[The technet page on the process is here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754489.aspx).

- [You will need the CA's certificate in your Trusted Root certificate store](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariae/archive/2007/12/12/ssl-configuration-and-reporting-services.aspx).  Major commercial CAs will be there, but if you use an internal CA or a self-signed certificate, your CA may or may not be there, and needs to be.

[You can then use the Reporting Services Configuration tool to configure SQL Reporting Services to use your certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345223%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).  (Third section, "Bind SSL to a Reporting Services URL Reservation")